# Getting net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, redux

I am trying to make simple login authentication using my REST api made using passport module in nodejs .
My frontend calls this function but this function returns an error and authentication does not occur . The post fn is not working .

[image: ERROR IN CONSOLE]

```
export const loginUser = (creds) => (dispatch) => {
    // We dispatch requestLogin to kickoff the call to the API
    dispatch(requestLogin(creds))

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'users/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type':'application/json' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(creds)
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log("HELLO");
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        } else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
        },
        error => {
            throw error;
        })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log("HELLO2");
        if (response.success) {
            // If login was successful, set the token in local storage
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
            localStorage.setItem('creds', JSON.stringify(creds));
            console.log(response);
            // Dispatch the success action
            // dispatch(fetchFavorites());
            dispatch(receiveLogin(response));
        }
        else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(loginError(error.message)))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason behind this was that my app was hosting static files as well as server together .
Thus, the server was responding with 404 file instead of  json data as response .
Resolved when i partitioned the client and server separately and hosted them on different platforms .